# SQL Server 2008 pivoting table with unknown column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

I am having trouble to pivot the following

```
    FirstName    LastName
    ----------------------
    Talyor       Swift
    Bruno        Mars
```

to the following

```
    ColumnName    ColumnValue
    --------------------------
    FirstName     Talyor
    LastName      Swift
    FirstName     Bruno
    LastName      Mars
```

I don't have any clue how to start this without hardcoding it especially the way to retrieve the column name from the system.

**Column Name in the source table is not given

Comment: Are you saying you aren't going to know the column names?

Comment: @bluefeet yes column names is unknown, which could be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "dynamic" approach which is accomplished via XML.

Clearly UNPIVOT would be more performant

**Example**

```
Select C.*
      ,ColumnOrder = D.ORDINAL_POSITION
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml) ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as n(r)
                 Cross Apply n.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
             ) C
 Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D on D.Table_Name='YourTable' and D.Column_Name=C.Item
```

**Returns**

```
Item        Value   ColumnOrder
FirstName   Talyor  1
LastName    Swift   2
FirstName   Bruno   1
LastName    Mars    2
```

**EDIT - Dynamic UnPivot**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='
Select ColumnOrder = D.ORDINAL_POSITION
      ,Item
      ,Value
 From  YourTable
 UnPivot (Value for Item in ('+Stuff((Select ',' +QuoteName(Name) 
                                       From  sys.columns 
                                       Where objecT_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable') 
                                       For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
                             +')) as UnPiv
 Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D on D.Table_Name=''YourTable'' and D.Column_Name=UnPiv.Item
'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Interesting but extremely nonreadable, nonmanageble. I wouldn't do it like that definitely.

Comment: In the first line of the code, if I don't know how many columns are there in the table and what are their names. What should be done to make that work?

Comment: @swordgit That is just a table variable used for demonstrative purposes.  Remove everything above the SELECT and replace (at)YourTable with your actual table name, view, or subquery.

Comment: @swordgit Simplified the example

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you it works! However, I am wondering if it is possible accomplish without using XML?

Comment: @swordgit Sure, but you would need to go dynamic.

Comment: @swordgit here is a link to dynamic unpivot  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996988/unpivot-all-columns-in-a-sql-table

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Would you mind to give an example on that too?

Comment: @swordgit See EDIT - Dynamic UnPivot

Comment: @JohnCappelletti in the XML example, why do we put the condition "Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('FieldsTo','Exclude')", What does the FieldsTo and Exclude do?

Comment: @swordgit Just an option to exclude certain fields (if desired).  Can be removed

Comment: @JohnCappelletti If I want to add the order position of that column in its table, would that be only take one more cross apply?

Comment: @swordgit Updated both options

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you! but the .Item does not work, I am using SQL server2008

Comment: @swordgit Not sure what you mean.  Both options are compatible with 2008.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti It gave me error saying "Invalid column name 'Item'." I guess it is thinking that item is one of the columns

Comment: @swordgit Assuming you are running the dynamic version.  This will execute on virtually any table.  Just make sure you replaced the 3 "YourTable" with your actual table name.  Can't seem to find a SQL Fiddle that supports 2008

Comment: @swordgit Do you have an issue with the XML version?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, basically when I did a Select * from anytable.item it does not work

Comment: @swordgit That wouldn't work in my world either.  The code provided will unpivot virtually any table.  ITEM does not exist unless you save the results into another table, view, or subquery.   Now, I'm not 100% clear on what your ultimate goal is.

Answer (score -1):

From what I see in the question this should work:

```
select 'firstname', firstname from table
union all
select 'lastname', lastname from table
```

If the column names are not known you can select them from `sys.columns` table, make a sql string and use `exec` function to execute sql string.

Comment: but sys.columns gave me all columns from all tables, what if I only need the column just for that table?

Comment: sys.columns table has a object_id column. sys.tables has also that column, so you can filter by it.